# calculating rowwise minimum of two series?

Tags: python-polars

Hi;

Is there any function that can generate a serie by calculating rowwise minimum of two series.? Functionality will be similar to np.minimum

a = [1,4,2,5,2]
b= [5,1,4,2,5]

np.minimum(a,b) -> [1,1,2,2,2]

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
q =df.lazy().with_column(pl.when(pl.col("a")>pl.col("b")).then(pl.col("b")).otherwise(pl.col("a")).alias("minimum"))

df = q.collect()
```

i didn't tested it but this should work i think

Comment: That should work. And you don't have to wrap it in a `.lazy() -> collect()`. The expressions also run on a DataFrame.

Comment: I wonder if you create an Expr like np.minimum, will it boost performance? (I did not mean that proposed one is slow. Performance of polars is impressive.)

Answer (score 3):

As the accepted answer states, you can use `pl.when -> then -> otherwise` expression.

If you have a wider DataFrame, you can use the `DataFrame.min()` method, `pl.min` expression, or a `pl.fold` for more control.

```py
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({
    "a": [1,4,2,5,2],
    "b": [5,1,4,2,5],
    "c": [3,2,5,7,2]
})

df.min(axis=1)
```

This outputs:

```
shape: (5,)
Series: 'a' [i64]
[
    1
    1
    2
    2
    2
]
```

## Min expression

When given multiple expression inputs to a `pl.min` the minimum is determined row-wise instead of column-wise.

```py
df.select(pl.min(["a", "b", "c"]))
```

Outputs:

```
shape: (5, 1)
┌─────┐
│ min │
│ --- │
│ i64 │
╞═════╡
│ 1   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   │
└─────┘
```

## Fold expression

Or with a `fold` expression:

```py
df.select(
    pl.fold(int(1e9), lambda acc, a: pl.when(acc > a).then(a).otherwise(acc), ["a", "b", "c"])
)
```

```
shape: (5, 1)
┌─────────┐
│ literal │
│ ---     │
│ i64     │
╞═════════╡
│ 1       │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1       │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2       │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2       │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2       │
└─────────┘
```

The `fold` allows for more cool things, because you operate over expressions.

So we could for instance compute the `min` of the squared columns:

```py
pl.fold(int(1e9), lambda acc, a: pl.when(acc > a).then(a).otherwise(acc), [pl.all()**2])
```

Or we could compute the min of square root of column "a" and the rest of the columns is squared.

```py
pl.fold(int(1e9), lambda acc, a: pl.when(acc > a).then(a).otherwise(acc), [pl.col("a").sqrt(), pl.all().exclude("a")**2])
```

You get the idea.

Comment: How would I get the row-wise minimum value of an List[Int32] column?

Answer (score 1):

It's 2023 and polars has [`min_horizontal`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.min_horizontal.html#polars.min_horizontal). Warning: It ignores `None`(s) but respects `np.nans`.

```py
import polars as pl
import numpy as np

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "a": [1, 4, 2, 5, 2],
        "b": [5, 1, 4, None, 5],
        "c": [3, 2, 5, 7, np.nan],
    }
)
df = df.with_columns(
    pl.min_horizontal(["a", "b", "c"]),
)
print(df)
```

yielding

```
shape: (5, 4)
┌─────┬──────┬─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b    ┆ c   ┆ min │
│ --- ┆ ---  ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64  ┆ f64 ┆ f64 │
╞═════╪══════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 5    ┆ 3.0 ┆ 1.0 │
│ 4   ┆ 1    ┆ 2.0 ┆ 1.0 │
│ 2   ┆ 4    ┆ 5.0 ┆ 2.0 │
│ 5   ┆ null ┆ 7.0 ┆ 5.0 │
│ 2   ┆ 5    ┆ NaN ┆ NaN │
└─────┴──────┴─────┴─────┘
```